# How to view form data in content in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to display data from a form as a table in content in one menu. 
I want users to be able to view the collected data. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

I searched and found modules. I have used ArtForms module.
Users are able to fill form in one menu, but are not able to view it in other menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

Create a module that have your forms. For module development [tutorial](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial)

And create an article and set the module inside that like.

```
{loadposition contact_form_pos}
```

Inside your article just mention the module position like above for [more](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article?)

Comment: I want to: user may fill the form and user must be able to see filled form. After 10 days, user's filled form must be red highlighted. Any advice?

Comment: you have to create your own module with your requirement. If you have a module then you can simply set the module positions inside the content (articles) and assign that to menu is that clear ?

Comment: I cannot create module. I am new to joomla.

Comment: Its not a big deal you can just download the sample module from above link and inside default page you can create form with your own fields.Also the users data needs to save on a new table.

Comment: Could you advise me another solution? Does ChronoForms module have this ability to display filled form for all users?

Comment: Then simply create your form with ChronoForms module and set the module position like above and set proper menu assignments too.